# depends only on A, but? not on B

Tags: conjunctions

"X depends only on A, [but] not on B" - with or without "but"? Any difference in meaning? Any stylistic arguments for or against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers explain well the redundancy of mentioning B because it and any other propositions are excluded by saying “**... only** on A”. But there are contextual circumstances in which it may be mentioned for reasons of style.

The conjunction *but* introduces a statement that limits or stands in contrast to a prior statement or proposition.

For a simple and topical example: “*It has been suggested that death rate is influenced by Covid {A} and by the number of G5 masts {B}. It depends only on Covid {A} but not on a few structures standing in fields {B}*”. The formally unnecessary repetition of B is used to emphasise its irrelevance.

Answer (score 1):

Well . . . formally if X depends ONLY on A, any statement about B is superfluous. 
But if you want to include B for emphasis either construction works, but I'd advocate for losing the comma if you include the "but".

Answer (score 1):

If you are clarifying a situation with somebody who thinks X may depend on both A and B I would suggest either "X depends only  on A, not on B" or "X depends on A, but not on B". Using "but" assumes there is a possibility that X might depend on B, but using "only" states there is no such possibility.

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of functional logic, "not on B" is a [logical redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_redundancy).

If I wanted to explicitly repeat that X is independent of B, I would write an aside (and I propose):

> X depends only on A. (*B does not affect X!*)